# Solidity - ImportError: cannot import name 'VRFCoordinatorMock' from 'brownie'

Tags: python, solidity

Would really appreciate any help on this error. I've tried several things and reviewed the contracts for VRF, but I can't seem to figure it out. All the other threads seem to solve it by moving their file, but mine is in the correct place. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Is it possible I'm pulling from the wrong address in my .yaml file?

Here is my bronwie-config.yaml:

[image]

Here is my deploy script:

```
from brownie import(network, config, accounts, MockV3Aggregator, VRFCoordinatorMock, LinkToken, Contract)
from web3 import Web3

FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS = ['mainnet-fork-dev']
LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = ['development','ganache-local']

def get_account(index = None, id = None):
    if index:
        return accounts[index]
    
    if id:
        return accounts.load(id)
    
    if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS or network.show_active() in FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS:
        return accounts[0]

    
    return accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])

contract_to_mock = {
    'eth_usd_price_feed': MockV3Aggregator, 'vrf_coordinator': VRFCoordinatorMock, 'link_token': LinkToken
}
def get_contract(contract_name):
    '''This function will grab the contract addresses from brownie config if defined. 
       Otherwise, it will deply a mock version of that contract, and retrun that mock contract.
            Args:
                contract_name (string)
            returns:
                brownie.network.contract.ProjectContract: the most recently deployed version of
    '''
    contract_type = contract_to_mock[contract_name]
    if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        if len(contract_type) <= 0:
            deploy_mocks()
        contract = contract_type[-1]
        #MockV3Aggregator[-1]
    else:
        contract_address = config['networks'][network.show_active()][contract_name]
        contract = Contract.from_abi(contract_type._name, contract_address, contract_type.abi)
        #MockV3Aggregator.abi
    return contract


DECIMALS = 8
INITIAL_VALUE = 200000000000

def deploy_mocks(decimals= DECIMALS, initial_value= INITIAL_VALUE):
    account = get_account()
    MockV3Aggregator.deploy(decimals, initial_value, {'from':account})
    link_token = LinkToken.deploy({'from':account})
    VRFCoordinatorMock.deploy(link_token.address,{'from':account})
    print('deployed')
```

Directory:

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you solved this ?

Comment: No, I still haven't.

Comment: From where are you importing the `VRFCoordinatorMock` ? I can't find it in the OpenZeppelin repo (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/mocks).

Answer (score 0):

You have used VRFConsumerBase version 1 and added address of version 2 in .yaml file. VRF_Coordinator address in brownie-config.yaml for version 1 must be taken from [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/v1/).